# Why does 2.ceil() throws exception whereas 2.3.ceil() returns 3 in prototype.js?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

To make it more generic ... I change the prototype of Number object in Javascript by doing this

```
Number.prototype.ceil = function() { return Math.ceil(this); };
```

Now 2.3.ceil() returns 3 and 2.ceil() throws exception.
But if I do b=2 and then do b.ceil() , it works fine!! So, basically it is still a problem of javascript.

Comment: AFAIK that's not Javascript, unless you're doing something funky with prototypes. If I wanted to `ceil` a number I'd do: `Math.Ceil(x)`

Comment: Yeah you are right...It is my mistake.

Comment: @Narendra... ceil() is **not** a built-in function of Number object. You must be using a 3rd party library that monkey-patches this functionality onto the Number type. I suspect you're using `prototype.js`. Let us know.

Comment: `> 2.3.ceil()`
`TypeError: Object 2.3 has no method 'ceil'`

Comment: My mistake ...I was using chrome console of a page which was using prototype.js ...Looks like it is a bug in their code.

Comment: But still there is this buggy behavior after doing this Number.prototype.ceil = function() { return Math.ceil(this); }; Now 2.3.ceil() returns 3 and 2.ceil() throws exception.But if I do b=2 and then do b.ceil() , it works fine!! So, basically it is still a problem of javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is `Math.ceil`, it's not an instance method.

```
var b = 2;
console.log(Math.ceil(b));

b = 2.3;
console.log(Math.ceil(b));
```

It looks like it would be trivial to create a prototype method that can do this:

```
Number.prototype.ceil = function() {
    return Math.ceil(this);
};

console.log(2.3.ceil());
```

It also looks like JavaScript reserves the first decimal in numeric literals for adding decimals to the number. This is a language feature. To get around this, you need two decimals:

```
2.ceil(); // does not work
2.3.ceil(); // does work
2..ceil(); // does work
```

Comment: I suspect OP is doing something strange with prototypes. In fact Prototype.js offer this: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/number/ceil Why would they do that though? It's both confusing and pointless.

Comment: Could be, but then the question should've been tagged appropriately ;)

Comment: I changed the tags now to reflect the problem in prototype.js ... Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: But still there is this buggy behavior after doing this 
Number.prototype.ceil = function() {
    return Math.ceil(this);
};
Now 2.3.ceil() returns 3 and 2.ceil() throws exception.But if I do b=2 and then do b.ceil() , it works fine!! So, basically it is still a problem of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`2.ceil()` looks like it'd be a syntax error.  (The interpreter might be confused about the dot -- it'd try to interpret the dot as part of the number.)

See if `2..ceil()` (note the double dots) or `(2).ceil()` works for you.

Comment: Nope (2).ceil() also does not work. BTW I am using chrome console to check this. But 2.3.ceil() returns 3 as expected.

Comment: @Downvoter: You may not like that `ceil` is an instance method, but in his case it is (or `2.3.ceil()` would fail as well).

Comment: @Narendra: are you sure about that? Try 2.4.ceil() and see if it returns 3 or 4.

Comment: It is unexpected behavior of prototype.js ...I edited the question to reflect it properly now.

Comment: `2..ceil()` and `(2).ceil()` both work for me in the Chrome console, once there's a `Number.prototype.ceil`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to do any of that, unless you have some kind of framework or something that is prototyping .ceil() as a method, in which case it is probably prototyping it as a method on strings.  IOW .ceil() isn't a native javascript method.

Javascript's native "round up" method .ceil() works by using the Math object like

```
alert(Math.ceil(2.3));
```

Comment: See http://www.prototypejs.org/api/number/ceil .  At least one popular framework does this.

Comment: But still there is this buggy behavior after doing this Number.prototype.ceil = function() { return Math.ceil(this); }; Now 2.3.ceil() returns 3 and 2.ceil() throws exception.But if I do b=2 and then do b.ceil() , it works fine!! So, basically it is still a problem of javascript.